# How to mark checkbox of the modal with jquery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap modal and jquery. I am dragging field into form builder and it opens the modal with form below. I want to check  id="edit-address" as shown as the modal opens with jquery.
I tried a different ways like
$('#edit-address').click(); $('#edit-address').prop('checked',true); etc but this is not working. May be i am not able to find the correct selectors.

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">

        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header text-center">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h3 class="semibold modal-title text-primary" style="text-transform: capitalize;">Heading</h3>
        </div>
        <!-- End Modal Header -->

        <div class="modal-body pb0">
            <div class="form-group formtemplate mb0">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="panel form-horizontal form-bordered form-canvas" name="form-profile">
                            <div class="panel-body pt0 pb0">

                                <div class="form-group no-border">

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <label for="edit-address-label" class="control-label mb5">Name:</label>
                                            <input id="edit-address-label" type="text" class="form-control fieldNames" data-option="label" placeholder="The question and name for this field..">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6 mt20 pt10">
                                            <div class="checkbox custom-checkbox">
                                                <input id="edit-address-required" type="checkbox" data-option="required" value="1">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row mt10">

                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-1 mt20 pt10">
                                                <div class="checkbox custom-checkbox">
                                                    <input class="check-address-checkbox" id="edit-address" type="checkbox" data-option="edit-address" value="1">
                                                    <label for="edit-address" checked="">Mark it</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: $('#edit-address').prop(':checked',true)

Comment: this should work but this is not working, maybe i am not able to get selector

Comment: did you use ":" before "checked" as I wrote?

Comment: yes i wrote checked

Comment: ":checked", not just "checked"

Answer (score 0):

The .click() method should work in your case
Check the console to see if you have any jquery issues

Here's a very simple example you can try:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Checkbox</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="btn">Tick</button>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="check"> Check
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js""></script>
        <script>
            $('#btn').click(function () {
                $('#check').click();
                console.log(" Checked");
            });</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $('#edit-address').attr('checked', true);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.